# VerticalTab Material React UI is overflowing by tab content

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I'm trying to use [this component](https://material-ui.com/pt/components/tabs/#guias-verticais), but when i put a content big than my Grid size, the content is overflowing my VerticalTab, as you can see in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gr046?file=/demo.js)
This is what i tried:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        className={classes.tabs}
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        <Tab label="Item Four" {...a11yProps(3)} />
        <Tab label="Item Five" {...a11yProps(4)} />
        <Tab label="Item Six" {...a11yProps(5)} />
        <Tab label="Item Seven" {...a11yProps(6)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            ELemento 1 sadasdasdasdasdadadad
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            Elemento 2 sadasdasdasdasdasdasd dsadasdasdsadasdsadasdadaddsadasd
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item one
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
);
```

As you can see, the content in my `<Grid>` is overflowing my `<Tabs>`. There's other element that i have to put instead the `<Grid>`?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the device size. It happens in the example in material ui doc as well(https://codesandbox.io/s/kxsqg?file=/demo.js)
This happens because of the overflow: hidden property in .MuiTabs-root class. Overriding it should solve the issue.